# Find infinite sum of $x=2.30909...$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So first I looked at $x=2.30909...$ as $2.3+0.00909...$.
$2.3$ I did $2.3={1\over 1-q}$ then I get $q={13\over 23}$. So the infinte sum of $2.3$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\left(\frac{13}{23}\right)}^n=2.3$$
Then I did that the infinite sum of $0.00909...$ is
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} 9\cdot10^{-2n+1}=0.00909...$$
I need to combine this 2 infinte sums to 1 infinte sum. But how do I make the infinite sum that start by $n=2$ so it will start from $n=0$? Can you explain the steps from changing from $n=2$ to $n=0$? 
And please also explain to me how I could think in the beginning about an infinite sum for the $0.00909$ so it will already start by $n=0$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If all you want is an expression in form $p/q$ for the given decimal representation of a rational number, then it's a trivial high school task. The desired fraction is $(2309-23)/990$. So much detail only adds to confusion and not clarity.

Comment: In the second sum replace $n$ everywhere that it appears with $n'.$ Then  substitute  $n'=n+2.$ Now $n'$  goes from $2$ up, so $n=n'-2$ goes from $0$ up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a substitution of $n=m-2$.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{13}{23} \right)^n=\sum_{m=2}^\infty \left(\frac{13}{23} \right)^{m-2}$$

Hence

$$2.30909\ldots= \sum_{m=2}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{13}{23} \right)^{m-2}+9\cdot 10^{-2m+1}\right]$$

Alternatively, if you want to start from zero. Just do similar transformation of $n=m+2$.

$$2.30909\ldots = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{13}{23} \right)^{m}+9\cdot 10^{-2m-3}\right]$$

Remark: The expected answer could simply be

\begin{align}2.3 + 9\sum_{m=0}^\infty  10^{-2m-3}&=2.3 + \frac{9}{1000}\sum_{m=0}^\infty  10^{-2m}\\
&= \frac{23}{10}+\frac{9}{1000}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{100}}\\
&=\frac{23}{10}+\frac{1}{110}\\
&=\frac{254}{110}\\
&=\frac{127}{55}\end{align}

Notice that in this question, we started from the answer and just want a series representation.

Comment: I need to start from n=0 because then I need to calculate the sum of them, it will be easier with geometric series formula.
But why when I make it start from $n=0$ I do $n=m+2$ an not $n=m-2$? I remove 2 no?
And what is the sense of doing that I don't understand...?

Comment: Your new index is $m$ in this case, hence $m=n-2$, hence it starts from $0$.